# How to kill UWP app in Windows 10?

Tags: uwp

I am working on UWP background task. Every time I try to run using Visual Studio, I need to uninstall to relaunch application because the application is running in background.

Is there any way to kill running UWP process? Because I am not able to see my process name in task manager.

Comment: To confirm, you're looking at the "Details" tab, not the Processes tab? Are you running as an Administrator-level user? What about using a tool like Process Explorer?

Comment: @Dai Yes, I am looking at Details tab, and I have opened task manager as Administrator.

Comment: It's possible VS is running it inside another process, do you see any "vshost.exe" processes?

Comment: @Dai No vshost.exe  not running.

Comment: There are no need to kill any process. UWP Background task is NOT a resident one - it will run when the predefined event has occurred. You can't find the 'process' from task manager. You can just run the app from your visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the app is running foreground, you should be able to find it in task manager and stop it. If you mean you want to stop the running [out of process background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task), as pnp0a03 said you cannot find the app process from task manager. Actually you should be able find `backgroundTaskHost.exe` process which may be the process for all background tasks.

If you want to control to stop the background task, please add the un-register feature for the app to control it. Details for how to do please reference [`BackgroundTask`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTask) official sample. And you could run the app from visual studio without uninstall.